# Listview inside gridview android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want show listview as a grid items how can I?I have tried it but when I call setadapter method for populating data into listview inside gridview's getview method data is not being populated.

Comment: u should post the code u tried and `Logcat` error msg if any.

Comment: I am not getting this why are you using grid view if you want to create list view inside gridview.. you can use multiple listview uusing linearlayout with gravity .. try different possibilities.

Comment: thanks for your help solved issue.The issu was that data is not being added to arraylist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont understand why you are adding a listview to gridview....this can make your application slow...just take a linear layout with a vertical orientation as item of a gridview..and add required elements dynamically to this linear layout according to the need...it will look same as listview in gridview...but will work with a much better speed...

Let me know if you want more description or a sample code....

Comment: Hi Hardeep, could you pls share some sample code for this.. i was trying to implement similar thing.. but I need to select one of the list items, so I have added listview as a gridview element